# Intellij not generating module dependencies from Gradle multi-module project

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have this minimal project structure, where `core` is supposed to depend on `common`:

```
myproj/
    core/
        build.gradle.kts
    common/
        build.gradle.kts
    build.gradle.kts
    settings.gradle.kts
```

**`myproj/build.gradle.kts`**:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

subprojects {
    version = "0.1"
}
```

**`myproj/settings.gradle.kts`**:

```
rootProject.name = "myproj"

include("myproj-common")
project(":myproj-common").projectDir = File("common")
include("myproj-core")
project(":myproj-core").projectDir = File("core")
```

**myproj/core/build.gradle.kts**:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.11"
}

dependencies {
    compile(project(":myproj-common"))
}
```

**myproj/common/build.gradle.kts**:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.11"
}
```

When I import this setup into IntelliJ, it finishes successfully, but if I open the module settings for `myproj-core`, `myproj-common` is not in the dependencies.  What am I missing here?

I'm using IntelliJ 2018.3 Community, and Gradle 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the "problem" was - I wasn't looking at the right place.

When importing a project, by default IntelliJ creates one module **per source set**. For example, under module `myproj.myproj-core`, it creates two separate modules `myproj.myproj-core.main` and `myproj.myproj-core.test`, each corresponding to one of the source sets. The module dependencies are then added at these sub-submodule levels. So `myproj.myproj-core.main` depends on `myproj.myproj-common.main`, and similarly for the test module.

If I import the project with the "create separate module per source set" cleared off, it won't create those sub-submodules, and `myproj.myproj-core` simply depends on `myproj.myproj-common`.